# Equivalent to getLines in Apache Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Scala program that works fine on a single computer. However, I'd like to get it working on multiple nodes.

The start of the program looks like this:

```
val filename = Source.fromFile("file://...")

val lines = filename.getLines

val linesArray = lines.map(x => x.split("   ").slice(0, 3))

val mapAsStrings = linesArray.toList.groupBy(_(0)).mapValues(x => x.map(_.tail))

val mappedUsers = mapAsStrings map {case (k,v) => k -> v.map(x => x(0) -> x(1).toInt).toMap}
```

When trying to use Spark to run the program I know I need a `SparkContext` and `SparkConf` object, and they are used to create the `RDD`.

So now I have:

```
class myApp(filePath: String) {

private val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myApp")
private val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
private val inputData = sc.textFile(filePath)
```

`inputData` is now an `RDD`, its equivalent in the previous program was `filename` (I assume). For an `RDD` the methods are different. So, what is the equivalent to `getLines`? Or is there no equivalent? I'm having a hard time visualising what the `RDD` gives me to work with, e.g. is `inputData` an `Array[String]` or something else?

Thanks

Comment: the Rdd is a collection(immutable) created from your input data, Source.fromFile("file://...") reads from the local fs in local mode. On the cluster you use the hdfs fs url, which can look like "hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/data/sample.log" everything else is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An RDD is a distributed collection, so conceptually it's not very different to a List, an Array or a Seq, providing you with functional operations that lets you transform the collection of elements. The main difference with the Scala collections is that an RDD in inherent distributed. Given a Spark cluster, when an RDD is created, the collection it represents is partitioned over some nodes of that cluster.

`rdd.textFile(...)` returns an `RDD[String]`.  Given a distributed file system each worker will load a piece or that file into a 'partition', where further transformations and actions (in Spark lingo) can take place.

Given that the Spark API resembles quite closely the Scala collections API, once you have an RDD, applying functional transformations on it is quite similar to what you would do using a Scala collection.

Your Scala program can therefore be easily ported to Spark:

```
//val filename = Source.fromFile("file://...")
//val lines = filename.getLines
val rdd = sc.textFile("file://...")

//val linesArray = lines.map(x => x.split("   ").slice(0, 3))
val lines = rdd.map(x => x.split("   ").slice(0, 3))

//val mapAsStrings = linesArray.toList.groupBy(_(0)).mapValues(x => x.map(_.tail))
val mappedLines = lines.groupBy(_(0)).mapValues(x => x.map(_.tail))

//val mappedUsers = mapAsStrings map {case (k,v) => k -> v.map(x => x(0) -> x(1).toInt).toMap}
val mappedUsers = mappedLines.mapValues{v => v.map(x => x(0) -> x(1).toInt).toMap}
```

One important difference is that there's no associative 'Map' collection as an RDD. Therefore, the `mappedUsers` is a collection of tuples `(String, Map[String,String])`

Comment: Thanks, your explanation helped clear a lot up for me! My program is not fully working yet because of problems elsewhere in the code (as I used `foldLeft` which is not applicable to an RDD) but you've definitely helped me along the way!

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html) seems to answer this directly:

```
def textFile(path: String, minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions): RDD[String]
```

> Read a text file from HDFS, a local file system (available on all nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI, and return it as an RDD of Strings.

So `textFile` is the equivalent of both `fromFile` and `getLines`, and returns an RDD where each entry is a line from the file. `inputData` is the equivalent of `linesArray`